# Is this inequality involving sum of square roots possible?

Tags: inequality, expected-value

Let $0 \leq x_i \leq B$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $p, q$ be discrete probability distributions over $\{1, \dots, n\}$. Does the following inequality hold?

\begin{align}
\left|\sqrt{\sum_i x_i p_i} - \sqrt{\sum_i x_i q_i} \right| \leq \sqrt{B} \sum_i \left|\sqrt{p_i} - \sqrt{q_i} \right|
\end{align}

**My thoughts:** This inequality holds for $n = 1$. I am not sure if this holds for $n= 2$ but I think if the inequality is correct one can use an inductive argument to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution by squaring both sides. The red part is a direct application of [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysInequality.html).
\begin{align*}
\color{red}{\sum_i x_i\sqrt{p_iq_i}} &\leq  \color{red}{\sqrt{\left(\sum_i x_ip_i\right) \left(\sum_i x_iq_i\right)}} + \sum_{i \neq j} \left|\sqrt{x_ix_j}(\sqrt{p_i} - \sqrt{q_i})(\sqrt{p_j} - \sqrt{q_j}) \right| \\
\implies \sum_i  x_i p_i + \sum_i x_i q_i \color{red}{- 2 \sqrt{\left(\sum_i x_ip_i\right) \left(\sum_i x_iq_i\right)}} &\leq \color{red}{\sum_i} \left( x_ip_i + x_iq_i \color{red}{- 2 x_i\sqrt{p_iq_i}} \right) + 2 \sum_{i \neq j} \left|\sqrt{x_ix_j}(\sqrt{p_i} - \sqrt{q_i})(\sqrt{p_j} - \sqrt{q_j}) \right| \\
\implies \left(\left|\sqrt{\sum_i x_ip_i} - \sqrt{\sum_i x_iq_i} \right|\right)^2 &\leq \left(\sum_i \left|\sqrt{x_ip_i} - \sqrt{x_iq_i}\right|\right)^2 \leq  B \cdot \left(\sum_i \left|\sqrt{p_i} - \sqrt{q_i}\right|\right)^2\\
\implies \left|\sqrt{\sum_i x_ip_i} - \sqrt{\sum_i x_iq_i} \right| &\leq  \sqrt{B} \cdot \sum_i \left|\sqrt{p_i} - \sqrt{q_i}\right|\\
\end{align*}
Q.E.D